# What is the state of aggregation of iodine formed during electrolysis of molten nickel(II) iodide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox, electrolysis, oxidation-state

Assume the electrolysis of molten $\ce{NiI2(l)}$ (inert electrodes) in a cell. The cell with a heating element is in the room; the room is at $\pu{25 °C}$ and $\pu{101.3 kPa}.$

The half-reaction for oxidation at the anode would be

$$\ce{2 I^-(l) -> I2(\text{state}) + 2 e^-},$$

whereas the global reaction will be

$$\ce{NiI2(l) -> Ni(s) + I2(\text{state})}.$$

Given that iodine is solid at room temperature, should it be marked as a solid in the equations? However, given that the $\ce{NiI2}$ is liquid, I'd think that the newly synthesized iodine would be a gas for a while?

Also, what observations could one make during the electrolysis? I.e. will the iodine accumulate on the positive electrode as a solid, or will it exit the cell in the form of a gas?

---

Also, is the reduction potential for

$$\ce{I2(s) + 2 e^- -> 2 I^-(\color{red}{aq})}$$

the same as for

$$\ce{I2(s) + 2 e^- -> 2 I^-(\color{red}{l}) }?$$

Comment: ?!? $\ce{NiI2}$ melts at 780 °C. How are you going to have liquid $\ce{NiI2}$ in a cell at 25 °C?

Comment: The cell is not at 25 deg C. The room in which the cell is is at 25 C.

Comment: Well iodine boils at 184 °C. What do you think will happen to it?

Comment: My guess is that the iodine will be a gas.

Comment: I took a liberty to correct formatting, rewrite the title and add a brief detail that your cell has a heating element to avoid confusion with the RT and m.p. of the salt (you got me here, too). Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: The half cell reduction reactions should be: $\ce{I2(s) + 2e- -> 2 I-}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, during the electrolysis process of molten nickel(II) iodide ($\ce{NiI2}$), $\ce{I– (l)}$ ions would be oxidized to $\ce{I2 (g)}$ at the anode, and $\ce{Ni^2+ (l)}$ ions would be reduced to $\ce{Ni (s)}$ at the cathode. My state assignments were based on following facts assuming the temperature of electrolytic cell is kept below $\pu{900 ^\circ C}$:

- Melting point of $\ce{NiI2}$ is about $\pu{797 ^\circ C}$. Therefore, electrolytic cell must be kept above $\pu{800 ^\circ C}$. Thus following equlibrium will be maintained during electrolysis: $$\ce{NiI2 (l) <=> Ni^2+ (l) + 2I- (l)}$$
- Boiling point of $\ce{I2}$ is about $\pu{134 ^\circ C}$. Hence, $\ce{I2}$ would be released as a gas at anode.
- Melting point of $\ce{Ni^\circ}$ metal is about $\pu{1455 ^\circ C}$. Hence, $\ce{Ni}$ would be deposited as a solid at cathode. If you want to keep nickel metal in liquid form, your electrolytic cell must be kept above $\pu{1500 ^\circ C}$.

I think I have given enough information you to figure out the rest.